# Fechar um form está fechado todos

Tags: delphi-10

Tenho 2 forms em uma aplicação Delphi. Quando abro o sistema para realizar o cadastro eu abro os dois forms, o principal e o de cadastro.
O Problema vem quando eu tento fechar o form de cadastro pois ele fecha todo o sistema e não sei o que fazer... vou deixar abaixo os códigos.

- Camada do form de Cadastro.

  ```
  procedure TfrmPrincipal.btnClienteClick(Sender: TObject);
  begin
  if frmCliente = nil then
    Application.CreateForm(TfrmCliente, frmCliente);

  frmCliente.Parent := frmPrincipal;
  frmCliente.Show;

  frmPrincipal.pnTelaPrincipal_Titulo1.Enabled := False;
  frmPrincipal.pnNavegacao.Enabled             := False;
  frmPrincipal.pnBaseManutencao01.Enabled      := False;
  end;
  ```
- Camada do form Close frmCliente.

  ```
  procedure TfrmCliente.btnCloseClick(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    frmPrincipal.pnTelaPrincipal_Titulo1.Enabled  := True;
    frmPrincipal.pnNavegacao.Enabled        := True;
    frmPrincipal.pnBaseManutencao01.Enabled := True;

    frmCliente.Close;

    frmPrincipal.AtualizaBotoesAdicionais;
  end;
  ```

Depois que o Breackpoint passa pelo `end;` do  `btnCloseClick` ele vai para o FormClose da frmPrincipal fechado todo o sistema.

```
procedure TfrmPrincipal.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  DM.qryUsoGeral.Close;
  DM.qryLocaliza.Close;

  FreeAndNil(TfrmPrincipal);
end;
```

Quero saber o por que disso e como reparar.

A pedido eu vou deixar aqui o .dpr

```
program Autosad;

{$R *.dres}

uses
  Windows,
  Vcl.Forms,
  UHPI in 'FONTES\Classe\UHPI.pas',
  UAcompanhamentoProcessos in 'FONTES\UAcompanhamentoProcessos.pas' {frmAcompanhamentoProcessos},
  UAlterarSenha in 'FONTES\UAlterarSenha.pas' {frmAlterarSenha},
  UAndamentoProcessual in 'FONTES\UAndamentoProcessual.pas' {frmAndamentoProcessual},
  UAtualizacoesVersao in 'FONTES\UAtualizacoesVersao.pas' {frmAtualizacoesVersao},
  UCentroCustos in 'FONTES\UCentroCustos.pas' {frmCentroCusto},
  UClienteAdicionais in 'FONTES\UClienteAdicionais.pas' {frmClienteAdicionais},
  UConsultas in 'FONTES\UConsultas.pas' {frmConsultas},
  UDataModuleGeral in 'FONTES\UDataModuleGeral.pas' {DataModuleGeral: TDataModule},
  UDataModuleGeral2 in 'FONTES\UDataModuleGeral2.pas' {DataModuleGeral2: TDataModule},
  UDataModuleGeral3 in 'FONTES\UDataModuleGeral3.pas' {DataModuleGeral3: TDataModule},
  UDataModuleRelatorios in 'FONTES\UDataModuleRelatorios.pas' {DataModuleRelatorios: TDataModule},
  UEmprestimos in 'FONTES\UEmprestimos.pas' {frmEmprestimos},
  UEntradaSistema in 'FONTES\UEntradaSistema.pas' {frmEntradaSistema},
  UEnviaEmailClientes in 'FONTES\UEnviaEmailClientes.pas' {frmEnviaEmailClientes},
  UFiltrosFluxoCaixa in 'FONTES\UFiltrosFluxoCaixa.pas' {frmFiltrosFluxoCaixa},
  UFiltrosGraficos in 'FONTES\UFiltrosGraficos.pas' {frmFiltrosGraficos},
  UFinanceiro in 'FONTES\UFinanceiro.pas' {frmFinanceiro},
  UFluxoCaixa in 'FONTES\UFluxoCaixa.pas' {frmFluxoCaixa},
  UGraficosEstatisticos in 'FONTES\UGraficosEstatisticos.pas' {frmGraficosEstatisticos},
  UInfoCliente in 'FONTES\UInfoCliente.pas' {frmInfoCliente},
  UManutencaoAdvogados in 'FONTES\UManutencaoAdvogados.pas' {frmManutencaoAdvogados},
  UManutencaoAgenda in 'FONTES\UManutencaoAgenda.pas' {frmManutencaoAgenda},
  UManutencaoAudiencias in 'FONTES\UManutencaoAudiencias.pas' {frmManutencaoAudiencias},
  UManutencaoBiblioteca in 'FONTES\UManutencaoBiblioteca.pas' {frmManutencaoBiblioteca},
  UManutencaoClientes in 'FONTES\UManutencaoClientes.pas' {frmManutencaoClientes},
  UManutencaoContasPagar in 'FONTES\UManutencaoContasPagar.pas' {frmManutencaoContasPagar},
  UManutencaoContatos in 'FONTES\UManutencaoContatos.pas' {frmManutencaoContatos},
  UManutencaoContratos in 'FONTES\UManutencaoContratos.pas' {frmManutencaoContratos},
  UManutencaoFornecedores in 'FONTES\UManutencaoFornecedores.pas' {frmManutencaoFornecedores},
  UManutencaoHonorarios in 'FONTES\UManutencaoHonorarios.pas' {frmManutencaoHonorarios},
  UManutencaoParametros in 'FONTES\UManutencaoParametros.pas' {frmManutencaoParametros},
  UManutencaoProcessos in 'FONTES\UManutencaoProcessos.pas' {frmManutencaoProcessos},  // <== Estou Utilizando esses From para fazer os testes 
  UManutencaoUnidades in 'FONTES\UManutencaoUnidades.pas' {frmManutencaoUnidades},
  UManutencaoUsuarios in 'FONTES\UManutencaoUsuarios.pas' {frmManutencaoUsuarios},
  UMudancaGrupalProcessos in 'FONTES\UMudancaGrupalProcessos.pas' {frmMudancaGrupalProcessos},
  UNovoCEP in 'FONTES\UNovoCEP.pas' {frmNovoCEP},
  UNovoFornecedor in 'FONTES\UNovoFornecedor.pas' {frmNovoFornecedor},
  UNovoModelo in 'FONTES\UNovoModelo.pas' {frmNovoModelo},
  UParteContrariaAdicionais in 'FONTES\UParteContrariaAdicionais.pas' {frmParteContrariaAdicionais},
  UPesquisaClientes in 'FONTES\UPesquisaClientes.pas' {frmPesquisaClientes},
  UPesquisaContasPagar in 'FONTES\UPesquisaContasPagar.pas' {frmPesquisaContasPagar},
  UPesquisaContatos in 'FONTES\UPesquisaContatos.pas' {frmPesquisaContatos},
  UPesquisaContratos in 'FONTES\UPesquisaContratos.pas' {frmPesquisaContratos},
  UPesquisaFornecedores in 'FONTES\UPesquisaFornecedores.pas' {frmPesquisaFornecedores},
  UPesquisaHonorarios in 'FONTES\UPesquisaHonorarios.pas' {frmPesquisaHonorarios},
  UPesquisaProcessos in 'FONTES\UPesquisaProcessos.pas' {frmPesquisaProcessos},
  UPublicacoes in 'FONTES\UPublicacoes.pas' {frmPublicacoes},
  USelecaoRelatoriosContasPagar in 'FONTES\USelecaoRelatoriosContasPagar.pas' {frmSelecaoRelatoriosContasPagar},
  USelecaoRelatoriosHonorarios in 'FONTES\USelecaoRelatoriosHonorarios.pas' {frmSelecaoRelatoriosHonorarios},
  USelecaoRelatoriosProcessos in 'FONTES\USelecaoRelatoriosProcessos.pas' {frmSelecaoRelatoriosProcessos},
  USplash in 'FONTES\USplash.pas' {frmSplash},
  UTelaPrincipal in 'FONTES\UTelaPrincipal.pas' {frmTelaPrincipal},
  UUtilitarios in 'FONTES\UUtilitarios.pas' {frmUtilitarios},
  UVisualizadorDeProcessos in 'FONTES\UVisualizadorDeProcessos.pas' {frmVisualizadorDeProcessos},
  UNovasPublicacoes in 'FONTES\UNovasPublicacoes.pas' {frmNovasPublicacoes},
  USobre in 'FONTES\USobre.pas' {frmSobre},
  Vcl.Themes,
  Vcl.Styles,
  UFuncoes in 'Fontes\Classe\UFuncoes.pas';

{$R *.res}
{$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP}
{$DEFINE IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE = $ 8000}
{$SetPEOptFlags IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE}
{$SetPEFlags IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED or IMAGE_FILE_REMOVABLE_RUN_FROM_SWAP or IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP}

begin
  {$IFDEF DEBUG}
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
  {$ENDIF}
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.Title             := 'Autosad - Gerenciador de Processos Jurídicos';
  Application.CreateForm(TDataModuleGeral, DataModuleGeral);
  Application.CreateForm(TDataModuleGeral2, DataModuleGeral2);
  Application.CreateForm(TfrmEntradaSistema, frmEntradaSistema);
  Application.CreateForm(TDataModuleGeral3, DataModuleGeral3);
  Application.CreateForm(TDataModuleRelatorios, DataModuleRelatorios);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: Edu, coloque o código de seu projeto (o dpr) aqui. Verifique, também, se os eventos estão ligados às procedures corretas.

Comment: No dpr o form principal da aplicação é o frmEntradaSistema. Não estão sendo criados automaticamente os dois forms que aparecem em seu código. Pelo código, dá pra ver que você está codificando ações de um form em outro. Isso não é muito bom. Vai criando um emaranhado que dificulta muito a manutenção, especialmente quando o projeto vai evoluindo. Possivelmente você está fazendo uma chamada incorreta, mas não está aparecendo no código que você postou. Coisas que podem estar acontecendo:

Comment: O form secundário é o principal da aplicação (primeiro Application.CreateForm); no object inspector um handler pode estar atribuído a evento errado, de outro form; um form que deveria ser filho ser o owner do outro.

Answer (score 0):

Passei por isso algum tempo atrás e no meu caso o `form02.Parent := form01;` o `OnKeyDown`, `OnKeyPress` e `OnKeyUp` do form02 não funcionava e ia para os respectivos eventos do Form01 então
eu coloquei tudo no evento form01.
Acho que não é a alternativa mais elegante mais funciona e ficou assim.

```
procedure TfrmTelaPrincipal.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  // Aqui, mesmo não tendo esses componentes na form pai eu coloquei assim por que o nome do Componente e identificado 
  if ((key = VK_RETURN) or (key = VK_DOWN)) and not (Pos(Copy(TControl(ActiveControl).Name,1,3),'cbb.dbc.dbg.mem.dbm')>0) then
    keybd_event(VK_TAB, 0, 0, 0); // pressiona o Tab

  if (key = VK_UP) and not (Pos(Copy(TControl(ActiveControl).Name,1,3),'mem.dbc.cbb.dbg') > 0) then
  begin
    keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, 0, 0);               // pressiona o Shift
    keybd_event(VK_TAB, 0, 0, 0);                 // pressiona o Tab
    keybd_event(VK_TAB, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);   // solta o Tab
    keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); // solta o Shift
  end;

  {$Region '  Referente aos Eventos do Form02. Passado para esse Evento pois no formulário filho não funciona  '}
  // Aqui eu coloquei para um componente especifico de cada Formulário 
  if (key = VK_RETURN) and (TControl(ActiveControl).Name = 'dbgConsultaClientes') then
  begin
    // Seu código aqui!!!
  end; {$EndRegion}
end;
```

Desse jeito funcionou e roda até hoje.

Comment: Valeu ai pela ajuda. Vou fazer um teste mais tarde! e aviso se deu certo.